# Can't set up nginx but my config file seems alright

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have a server at *176.227.213.2*. So I created a conf file for the default server (*default.conf*)

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name default 176.227.213.2;


    location / {
        root   /var/www/html;
        index  index.php index.html;
    }
.........
```

[Full config](http://pastebin.com/VBQqXMYK). But I am not able to get even a single index.html to work. No response from server. The access log is empty, which I assume means, nginx is not listening to request at all. I have doubled checked the path and files.

I don't realize what is the problem here.

**Update**: Output of,

*netstat -plutn*

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      590/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      855/sendmail: accep
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1991/php-fpm: maste
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      756/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3031/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      759/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      590/sshd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*                           759/perl
```

**Update 2**: After suggestion of @jamzed, I checked my iptables and realized that port 80 was not open. Added a rule for opening port, rebooted my system and it worked like a charm. Hope it helps!

Comment: You can not access your website or any else error?Please post your error here

Comment: @Gonuc: Absolutely nothing at all, Server takes too long to respond on my FF. Try 176.227.213.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connect from localhost to localhost:

$ printf "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc 127.0.0.1 80

or

$ telnet 127.0.0.1 80

Did you check firewall rules for port 80? also you can use tcpdump and check if the packets come to your webserver.

Comment: The printf command does give the right output. Does that indicate problem with Firewall? tcpdump gave a very verbose, never-ending, output

Answer (score 0):

Problem maybe `fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;`. Try change it to `fastcgi_pass   176.227.213.2:9000;`

Check your firewall rule, it can block traffic to 127.0.0.1